# How to add a numerator to each sub-collection of a multilevel collection?

Tags: groovy

I have this collection

```
[
    [Name:John, City:London],
    [Name:Rachel, City:Paris]
]
```

I want to add a numerator to each sub-collection so that the result will be

```
[
    [Number:1, Name:John, City:London],
    [Number:2, Name:Rachel, City:Paris]
]
```

I know of **eachWithIndex()** but it adds the numerator outside of the subcollection.

I would appreciate any idea.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially a one-liner:

```
def list = [     [Name:'John', City:'London'],     [Name:'Rachel', City:'Paris'] ]

def res = list.indexed().collect{ num, v -> v + [ Number:num + 1 ] }

assert res.toString() == '[[Name:John, City:London, Number:1], [Name:Rachel, City:Paris, Number:2]]'
```